# Best practice when iterating through string Python?

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity

When you're iterating through a string with a for each loop, is it better to convert the string to a list and then loop through it? The reason I'm asking is because strings are immutable, so I'm not sure if it becomes inefficient in some way?

So, is

```py
a = list("hello")
for i in a:
    pass
```

better than

```py
a = "hello"
for i in a:
    pass
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Strings are iterable.  You gain nothing by adding an extra operation (converting to a list).

Comment: If you want to "change" the string, either create a new one while looping, or convert to a list and `join` in the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been noted, the idiomatic way is to simply iterate through the string.  In fact the statement

```
a = list("hello")
```

**needs to iterate** through the string in order to create the list.

That said, if you are to be iterating through the same string, **many times**, then (after paying the cost of converting to a list) iteration through a **list is faster**

```
# string
$ python -m timeit -s "x='a'*10000" "for i in x: i"
10000 loops, best of 3: 137 usec per loop

# raw list
python -m timeit -s "x=list('a'*10000)" "for i in x: i"
10000 loops, best of 3: 113 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

It's more idiomatic to simply iterate over the string without converting it into a list:

```
word = "hello"
for letter in word:
    print(letter)
```

Comment: I believe the question is how is one approach better than the other.

Comment: The question is what's the best practice. This is the most pythonic solution, given the problem description. I can't think of any reason to call list(word) for the stated use case.